# SQL statement to concat strings in MySQL and SQL Server

Tags: java, hibernate

I worked on hibernate.
below code is worked fine in mssql but gives error in MySql

**Code:**

```
   Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(table1.class);
   criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("(select this11_.um_email as y0_ from table2 this11_ where this11_.id='"+IDvalue+"') like '%'+this_.post_id+'%'"));
```

**StackTrace :**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+this_.post_id+'%'' at line 1
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
```

can anybody help me to resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql doesn't allow the use of `+` with text; use `CONCAT()` instead:

```
... like CONCAT('%', this_.post_id, '%')
```

`CONCAT()` also works in MSSQL.

Comment: ya it works fine for mysql but it will not work for mssql.My application is connected with mssql and mysql.

Comment: @sejal `CONCAT()` is part of the SQL standard and works in mssql too. This solution works for both mysql and mssql.

Comment: when i try to execute this query in mssql then it will give error like "Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: @sejal `concat()` is supported by MSSQL. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh231515.aspx)

Comment: @Bohemian: `concat()` is only available in SQL Server since 2012. Earlier versions did not support that.

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("(select this11_.um_email as y0_ from table2 this11_ where this11_.id='"+IDvalue+"') LIKE CONCAT('%', {alias}.post_id ,'%')");
```

Comment: not getting error but query is generated wrong. its like ' like '%this_.post_id%' which gives wrong output..

Comment: @ Yogesh when i try to execute this query in mssql then it will give error like "Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: Sejal, definitely you are doing any mistake. same code works in my example. Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);  
  criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("(select e.emails from email e limit 1) LIKE CONCAT('%', {alias}.name , '%')"));

Comment: @ Yogesh,yes your example is correct for MySql.concat is working fine in MySQL but my Application is connected with MSSQL as well as MySql so this criteria is not Working for MSSQL Server 2008. In MSSQL 2008 this query gives error like " Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Answer (score 0):

You can create your query based on dialect of Database. Use `customQuery` string in your `Criteria`.

```
String customQuery = "";
SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();
Dialect dialect = ((SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory).getDialect();
String dialectString = dialect.toString();

if(dialectString.equals("org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect")){
    customQuery = "MSSQL_Query";
    ...
}else if(dialectString.equals("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect") 
        || dialectString.equals("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect")
        || dialectString.equals("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect")){
    customQuery = "MySQL_Query";
    ...
}
```